# Nested For Loops Explanation Needed

Tags: for-loop, methods

Basically, in this program, I was instructed to create an array of random numbers and then sort them smallest to largest by bubble sorting with for loops. With a bunch of trial and error, my buddy and I were able to figure it out but I just took a look back at my code and honestly, it's very hard to comprehend.. I'm not too familiar with nested loops so if someone could explain how this method is working, that would be awesome. More specifically, what does the value `j` and `i` stand for.

```
public void sort() {

    int val = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        for(int j = 1; j < (myArray.length - i); j++) {

             if(myArray[j-1] > myArray[j]) {

                 val = myArray[j-1];
                 myArray[j-1] = myArray[j];
                 myArray[j] = val;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Any answers are greatly appreciated, thanks guys/gals!

Comment: `i` and `j` are just loop variables - they don't *stand* for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` and `j` are short with no inherent meaning other than to represent the index you are at in the array. The first for loop is so that the second loop and the sorting method are repeated for as many items are in the array. The second loop does the sorting.

```
if(myArray[j-1] > myArray[j]) { // Checks if the index `j` in the array is less than the one before it.
    val = myArray[j-1]; // Temporarily stores the greater value.
    myArray[j-1] = myArray[j]; // Swap the numbers.
    myArray[j] = val; // Swap the numbers.
}
```